# Numbering Theorems/Definitions together, by section and without section symbol

Tags: sectioning, numbering, theorems

I am fairly new to LaTeX and I am looking for a particular style: I want to number my theorems/propositions/corollaries/definitions together and by section. For example, Definition 1.1, Theorem 1.2, Corollary 1.3, Theorem 1.4 etc. for results that are all in the first section. However, I would like to use the `$\S$` symbol in the section heading, eg:

[image]

But this means that I get Theorems and Propositions which include the `$\S$` symbol:

[image]

Which obviously, looks awful. Can anybody explain to me how I might get what I want? Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Do you want § also before subsection numbers?

Answer (score 6):

Load the package `titlesec` and add this line to your preamble:

```
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\S\thesection}{1em}{}[]
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{defn}[theorem]{Definition}

\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\S\thesection}{1em}{}[] 

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

\begin{defn}
definition
\end{defn}
\begin{proposition}
proposition
\end{proposition}
\begin{theorem}
theorem
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you would like to have the `\S` as a feature of the section number everywhere else that it occurs (such as cross-references), then you can define `\thesection` to contain a `\S` symbol first, and then define `\thetheorem`, *etc.* to remove this symbol as a part of creating the theorem number.

### Preamble.

Consider the following minimal preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\renewcommand\thesection{\S\arabic{section}}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\setTheoremCounterStyle[1]{%
    \expandafter\renewcommand\csname the#1\endcsname{%
        \expandafter\@gobble\thesection.\arabic{#1}}}
\makeatother

\setTheoremCounterStyle{theorem}
\setTheoremCounterStyle{proposition}
\setTheoremCounterStyle{definition}
```

The first several commands are fairly standard. The macro `\setTheoremCounterStyle` takes one argument consisting of a theorem-like environment `thmenv` (though any counter name will do), and defines the command `\thethmenv` to consist of `\thesection` — with the first symbol of it (in this case, `\S`) stripped away — followed by a dot and `\arabic{thmenv}`.

### Sample code.

A sample document using that preamble:

```
\begin{document}

\section{A section}
\label{sec:foo}
This is Section~\ref{sec:foo}.

\begin{definition} A definition. \end{definition}
\begin{proposition} A proposition. \end{proposition}
\begin{theorem} A theorem. \end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

### Output.

[image: Output from code above]

Answer (score 2):

An option which produces the same result as in **karlkoeller**'s answer, but without using `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{defn}[theorem]{Definition}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\addmark@section{\S}
\renewcommand*\@seccntformat[1]{%
  \csname addmark@#1\endcsname
  \csname the#1\endcsname\quad
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

\begin{defn}
definition
\end{defn}
\begin{proposition}
proposition
\end{proposition}
\begin{theorem}
theorem
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The above redefinitin of `\@seccntformat` will add `\S` just to sections; if you want to prepend the symbol to all sectional units, the redefinition would be

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\@seccntformat[1]{%
  \S\csname the#1\endcsname\quad
}
\makeatother
```